# for each outcome query different html code

Tags: php, mysql

```
   <?php       
        $query45 = "SELECT * FROM  `fietsen`"; 
        if ($result45 = $mysqli->query($query45)) {
            /* fetch object array */
           while ($obj45 = $result45->fetch_object()) {
                $materiaal = $obj45->materiaal;
                echo $materiaal;
                $query46 = "SELECT * FROM  `fietsen` where materiaal = $materiaal"; 

                if ($result46 = $mysqli->query($query46)) {
                    while ($obj46 = $result46->fetch_object()) {
                        echo " <div class=\"widget\">
                               <div class=\"title\"><h2>$materiaal</h2></div>
                               <ul class=\"nav nav-tabs nav-stacked\">";
                        echo " <li><a href=\"/fiets/$materiaal/$obj46->seotitel/\">$obj46->titel</a></li> ";
                     }
                     echo " </ul> </div>";
                }
           }
       }    

 ?>
```

For each outcome ($materiaal) on the query45 I need a new widget. I think i'm close but i'm breaking my head on this. 
My outcome is either just one 'material' or none. In the database there are 3 different type of materials, so there should be 3 widgets. In the widgets there should be only listed the bikes of that type of material.

**Update: The fix**

```
       <?php             

  $query45 = "SELECT * FROM  `fietsen` group by materiaal"; 
if ($result45 = $mysqli->query($query45)) {
    /* fetch object array */
    while ($obj45 = $result45->fetch_object()) {
$materiaal = $obj45->materiaal;


          echo " <div class=\"widget\">
                            <div class=\"title\"><h2>$materiaal</h2></div>
                            <ul class=\"nav nav-tabs nav-stacked\">";


  $query46 = "SELECT * FROM  `fietsen` where materiaal = '$materiaal'"; 
  $result46 = $mysqli->query($query46);
    while ($obj46 = $result46->fetch_object()) {

        $titel = $obj46->titel;
    echo "   <li><a href=\"/fiets/$materiaal/$obj46->seotitel/\">$obj46->titel</a></li> ";

    }





echo "</ul>";




    }     
}   

 ?>
```

Comment: Remove the second query and second loop. Focus on the first one first. How many `echo`s happen?

Comment: I get 3 echo's (in the first query)

Comment: So then the first query isn't your problem. You're getting 3 results which is what you said is expected. Are you sure that you want to be querying the same table (`fietsen`) in both queries? That doesn't seem to be very productive. Perhaps you meant to query a different table in the second query?

Comment: I fixed it. will change the first post

Comment: I'm still not sure what the point of querying the same table twice is. Why not just use `$obj45->materiaal`, `$obj45->seotitel`, and `$obj45->titel`?